# Regex not working when used on a Chinese text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I created a small python function to remove some undesired elements from strings written in Chinese. 
Those undesired elements feature an ampersand at the beginning (&Something). 
The function uses a regex to spot them, remove them and return the longest part of the string without those undesired elements, but for some reason it's not working as expected. 
I tested the function on strings in other languages and alphabets and it works as expected.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

def clean_sentence(my_text):
    split_the_text = re.split(r'([&].*?\s)', my_text)
    longest_sentence = max(split_the_text, key=len)

    return longest_sentence

my_string = "一个神奇的鸭子飞在与&SOMETHING然后唱支歌给&PERSON"
print clean_sentence(my_string)
```

That's the output:

```
õ©Çõ©¬þÑ×ÕÑçþÜäÚ©¡Õ¡ÉÚú×Õ£¿õ©Ä&SOMETHINGþäÂÕÉÄÕö▒µö»µ¡îþ╗Ö&PERSON
```

Comment: So what *does* happen? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Also, your example throws a name error: `split_the_copy` is not set. `my_string` is a bytestring; it may matter what codec was used to encode the text; perhaps you can give us the `print repr(my_string)` output so we can better determine what bytes are contained in it.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I fixed that!
About the goal: the string should return the longest part of the string without those undesired elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why Is this question unclear? He's seeking help for a regex which is not correct. One could argue about the wording, but the purpose including code sample seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Jan: it is missing a clear problem statement; how can future visitors know they have the same problem? The post is missing several components of the required [mcve]; no actual output nor is there expected output. The input also has issues; I asked for a `print repr(...)` sample of that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I updated the question including a working code and its output.I hope that can be understandable for other users. I am sorry if the original topic wan't clear enough but as you can see, this is one of my first questions here. For the future I'll try to be more accurate.

Comment: It's an improvement, but it doesn't tell us what you *expected* the output to be. And could you use `print repr(...)` rather than `print ...` (or in addition to), as that gives us type information and exact byte content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:
There is no whitespace but you require one. If your `SOMETHING` or `PERSON` are only english characters or digits, you might be able to get along with:

```
import re
def clean_sentence(my_text):
    split_the_text = re.split(r'&\w+', my_text)
    longest_sentence = max(split_the_text, key=len)

    return longest_sentence

my_string = "一个神奇的鸭子飞在与&SOMETHING然后唱支歌给&PERSON"
print(clean_sentence(my_string))
# 一个神奇的鸭子飞在与
```

Comment: Can you please correct the mistake in my code (which I assume is the regex)?